# Sending email with Nodemailer and Office 365 with OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, nodemailer, office365api

I am trying to use Nodemailer to send emails using Office 365 with OAuth2.

After many failed attempts, and many unauthorized errors, I got to the following code:

```
const config: Options = {
      service: 'office365',
      host: 'smtp.office365.com',
      port: 587,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: this.configService.get<string>('mail.senderMail'),
        clientId: clientId,
        clientSecret: clientSecret,
        accessUrl:
          'https://login.microsoftonline.com/2XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/token',
      },
      requireTLS: true,
      tls: {
        ciphers: 'SSLv3',
      },
    };
```

The problem now, I am getting an error saying:

> Can't create new access token for user

What am I doing wrong? Is there something wrong with my code? or am I doing this all wrong?

I am stuck for days now.